# JavaScript noob - having problems using window.setInterval() properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a Snake-like game with two modules. The first (let's call it "Main") handles the game's mechanics and the second ("MainUI") builds the UI and display based on the board state it receives from the mechanics module.

Main handles setInterval for both itself and for MainUI and sets the tick rate thus:

```
  var startGame = Main.startGame = function (displayCallback) {
    board.initialize();
    var container = function () {
      gameTick(displayCallback);
    }; // displayCallback is a function passed from the UI to visually render the board
    root.gameLoop = Main.gameLoop = window.setInterval(container, 200);
  };
```

So the game, and its display, is intended to update five times a second. It executes this code on every update:

```
  var gameTick = Main.gameTick = function (displayCallback) { // same callback
    if (isGameOver()) {
      gameOver();
    }
    player.update(); //update an array of the coordinates the player occupies
    board.update(); //recreate board state based on position of player
    board.display(displayCallback); //Board.display runs the externally-passed callback
  };
```

But the game seems to run far slower than it should. In fact, no amount of adjusting the setInterval time seems to make it faster beyond a certain point, say, half a second. I'm not sure if the problem is in inefficient mechanics code, if passing the display callback function around is causing problems, or if I'm using setInterval improperly, or if somehow the UI code is slowing it down.

The UI starts the mechanics module like this:

```
  var beginUpdates = MainUI.beginUpdates = function () {
    Main.startGame(updateBoard);
  };
```

And it updates the displayed board, an HTML table with unique CSS formatting for elements with specific classes, using jQuery like so:

```
  var updateBoard = MainUI.updateBoard = function (board) {
    for (var y = 0; y < board.length; y++) {
      for(var x = 0; x < board[0].length; x++) {
        var currentElement = $("td[data-y=" + y + "][data-x=" + x + "]")
        switch(board[y][x]) {
          case 0:
            currentElement.removeClass("snake");
            currentElement.removeClass("apple");
            break;
          case 1:
            currentElement.addClass("snake");
            currentElement.removeClass("apple");
            break;
          case 2:
            currentElement.removeClass("snake");
            currentElement.addClass("apple");
            break;
        }
      }
    }
  };
```

This function is from the UI module and is the callback that is passed into the mechanics module, where it is given the "board" object.

Can you guys tell me what might be going wrong here? I'll be happy to post more code. I apologize for the long post and for my cluelessness :\

Comment: [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval) returns intervalID. Does it fit into your system?

Comment: The setInterval() is intended in my app to give the intervalID to Main.gameLoop, where it's terminated (window.clearInterval(Main.gameLoop)) on game over.

Comment: Try to measure time (at first glance `updateBoard` should be measured). Remember start time an the beginning by `var start = new Date().getTime();` Then at the end use `console.log(new Date().getTime() - start)`. It will help to find a bottleneck (I believe you know where console output is :)).

Comment: If it is a performance problem, DOM manipulation would probably be a good place to start looking. See what the effect of removing everything but a log statement from your updateBoard function is. Also, how many elements are in the board?

Comment: I have simplified your code and the timer is working. Maybe the problem is in any of the underlying functions. Try the simplified example through the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sGuLf/1/). Besides, I see a lot of functions to be executed in only 200 millseconds. I could happen that the functions have not finished when the next timer is launched

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first try profiling your code and HTML updates. In Chrome this can be done using the Developer Tools.

**JS Profiling**

In the Profiles tab choose "Collect JavaScript CPU Profile" and click start. Start your game and play it for a 10 seconds or so. Again go to the Profiles tab and click stop. You will now be able to see if your code is taking longer than it should, although I suspect this is not the problem.

A way to speed this up may be to cache the jQuery elements themselves in an array instead of selecting them each time which will be slow. I would also give the TDs an ID instead of using data elements such as:

```
<table id="game">
  <tr>
    <td id="cell-0-0"></td>
    <td id="cell-1-0"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="cell-0-1"></td>
    <td id="cell-1-1"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And use a selector that is only selecting on IDs as these a very quick.

```
$('#cell-' + x + '-' + y);
```

**HTML Profiling**

This is more likely the problem. Depending on what you are doing with the CSS it may be causing [reflows](https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/reflow) on the page. To test for this, and your general HTML paint speed, open the developer tools and click the "Settings" (gear) icon. Here you can enable:

- Show paint rectangles : visual information on what is being repainted
- Force accelerated compositing : this allows the FPS meter
- Show FPS meter : shows you how fast the page is being repainted, and when

Comment: "A way to speed this up may be to cache the jQuery elements themselves in an array instead of selecting them each time which will be slow."

This was precisely the problem I was having. I took your advice and loaded each div element I created with jQuery into an array for quick lookup without any need to search the page for DOM elements. This was way, way more efficient. I have no slowdown problems now. I had no idea you could do that- Thank you!